# ELSE Statement for CSV file not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, if-statement, for-else

I'm trying to fit in an `ELSE` statement for a variable within a `CSV` File.

CSV File:

```
abcd, qwerty, aoo9
afjd, wijfs, aaaa
12as, 54as, oozz
```

I have attempted the following:

```
string1 = raw_input('User input: ')
with open('FILE.csv', "rb") as csvfile:
        z = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in z:
            if string1 in row[1]: 
                print 'A' 
            else:
                print 'B'
                sys.exit()
```

However, **regardless of whether the user's input is in** `row[1]` or not, it will still print '`B`'.

**I expect that if the user inputs `qwerty`, `wijfs`, or `54as` as string1 which all lie in `row[1]`, it will print '`A`', however if the user inputs something for string1 does is not in `row[1]`, it will print '`B`'**

I have also tried:

```
elif variable not in row [1]: #...
```

But that doesn't work either.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you inspect the contents of `row[1]` ? Also the elements are 0 based index. So, the first element is `row[0]`

Comment: Are you saying that rather than printing either 'A' or 'B', it will print 'A' or do nothing?

Comment: how is `variable` initialized?

Comment: It would help if you added an example line from the csv and a value for `variable` that you expected to result in A being printed.

Comment: I have done as suggested, any ideas? @EricAppelt

Comment: @Gabe Regardless of whether the variable inputted by the user is in `row [1]`, it will still print '`B`' which I believe applies for when the variable in not in the file

Comment: @V15I0N I have updated the code, it is initialised through a user input :)

Comment: works fine for me when I input `querty`. Is this an indexing misunderstanding? `row[1]` refers to the second row, `row[0]` to the first.

Comment: @EricAppelt I understand that, it just doesn't seem to work for me, regardless of whether the variable inputted by the user is in `row [1]`, it will still print '`B`' which I believe applies for when the variable in not in the file

Comment: It's still unclear what you are expecting to happen. What is the user input? For these kind of code examples it's more helpful to use fixed values like `variable="abcd"` and - if possible - avoid the dependency on external files.

Comment: Add the statement `print variable, row[1]` immediately above `if variable. . .` and you will immediately see the problem.

Comment: @Falko Okay, I expect that when the user enters a string that is in `row[1]` the program should print '`A`', when the user enters string that **is not** in `row [1]` it will print '`B`', I don't seem to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, that's what you wrote about five times now. But what is the value of `variable`? And where should it be contained in? Do you expect 'A' to be printed if the user inputs 'abcd' or 'querty' or 'y'?

Comment: @LarryLustig I see no problem of such :( It would just print out the user's `variable` and `row[1]`

Comment: @iAmNewToPYTHON: In the time it took you to write your comment, you could have done as suggested and had your problem solved.

Comment: @LarryLustig I've updated it to try and make myself more clear, sorry :(

Comment: @Falko `A` should be printed when the users input is in `row[1]`

Comment: Hard to be clearer -- print the strings and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, I'm out. As long as you're not following Larry's suggestion I don't see any point in following the discussion any further.

Comment: @Falko Okay, Thanks for your time anyway. I have followed Larry's suggestion but nor does that explain the problem.

Comment: @LarryLustig: "Add the statement `print variable, row[1]`..." In all fairness, it's unlikely that the problem would jump out at a beginning Python programmer from that print statement, since the only indication of the error would be the extra space in the printout. A better debugging print statement would be `print '(' + variable + ') (' + row[1] + ')'` or anything along those lines.

Comment: @MichaelGeary: True enough.  I expanded my comment to an answer and used angle brackets to call out extra white space.

Comment: @LarryLustig: Silly me, I didn't scroll down to see your answer before posting my comment. D'oh! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your CSV file contains spaces. Your program will behave as expected if you input `" querty"` instead of `"querty"`.

You can modify the CSV file or use the `strip` function to remove leading and trailing whitespace of `row[1]`.

Or use the `skipinitialspace` parameter of the `csv.reader`. ;)

Comment: Which would be obvious to the OP if he or she had taking the advice given and *printed the darn strings*.  Some people just won't allow themselves to be helped.

Comment: @LarryLustig: I totally agree with you.

Comment: @Falko Thanks for the suggestion, Although I tried this earlier and it didn't work, still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, either `variable` or `row[1]` does not contain what you think it contains.  Add a print statement as follows:

```
    for row in z:
        print '<{}> ?= <{}>'.format(variable, row[1]) # add this line.
        if variable in row[1]:
```

to see what's in those two variables (including leading or trailing white space).  Most likely, they will not contain what you think they contain.

Comment: I have done as you suggested, and they do contain exactly what I think they do :(

Comment: Please show the output, including the angle brackets.  Also, check the *type* of the two variables to ensure that you're not trying to compare string to unicode.

Comment: `<qwerty> ?= <qwerty> #New Line                                                                                                    B`

Comment: However if I enter `afjd` as the input, I would get: `<afjd> ?= <qwerty> #New Line B`

Comment: You *would* get, or you *do* get?

Comment: Now try `print '<{}> ?= <{}>'.format(type(variable), type(row[1]))`

Comment: I mentioned that above ;) If the user inputed qwerty, I'd get `<qwerty> ?= <qwerty>` and `B` would be printed on a new line. If the user inputted `afjd` as the input, it would print `<afjd> ?= <qwerty>` and still `B` on the new line. Thanks.

Comment: `print '<{}> ?= <{}>'.format(type(variable), type(row[1]))` would print `<<type 'str'>> ?= <<type 'str'>>  `

Comment: If you are running the example code then you should see a < qwerty> (a space between the angle bracket and the "q").  What code are you actually running?

Comment: I am running the example code, the full preview I receive is `<<type 'str'>> ?= <<type 'str'>>`                                                                                                                              
`A `                                                                                                                  
`<<type 'str'>> ?= <<type 'str'>>`                                                                                                                               
`B`

Comment: If it helps I'm on Python 2.7

Comment: If you are really running the posted code using the exact data you posted, you should be seeing `< qwerty>` instead of `<qwerty>`.  Can you explain where the missing space went?

Comment: My bad Larry, turns out there is a space :( Sorry mate. `<qwerty> ?= < qwerty> `

Comment: To add to this, it also printed `<qwerty> ?= < wijfs>`